# error C2280 class::class(const class&) attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++

У меня возникла непонятная ошибка, с которой не могу справиться, и не могу понять, откуда она возникла. Использую Visual Studio 2015.

> 1>dexmath.h(465): error C2280: '_4matrix::_4matrix(const _4matrix &)':
>   attempting to reference a deleted function
>
> 1>dexmath.h(484): note: compiler has generated '_4matrix::_4matrix'
>   here

**.h**

```
class D_EXPORT _4matrix
{
public:
    _4matrix
    (
        _point m00, _point m01, _point m02, _point m03,
        _point m10, _point m11, _point m12, _point m13,
        _point m20, _point m21, _point m22, _point m23,
        _point m30, _point m31, _point m32, _point m33
    );
    _4matrix(void);

    static _4matrix identity(void)
    {
        return _4matrix();
    }

    inline static _4matrix zero(void)
    {
        return _4matrix(
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
        );
    }

    union
    {
        _4point d_4p32[4];
        _point  d_p32[4][4];
        _32un   d_u32[4][4];
    };
};
```

**.cpp**

```
_4matrix::_4matrix
(
    _point m00, _point m01, _point m02, _point m03,
    _point m10, _point m11, _point m12, _point m13,
    _point m20, _point m21, _point m22, _point m23,
    _point m30, _point m31, _point m32, _point m33
)
{
    d_p32[0][0] = m00;
    d_p32[0][1] = m01;
    d_p32[0][2] = m02;
    d_p32[0][3] = m03;

    d_p32[1][0] = m10;
    d_p32[1][1] = m11;
    d_p32[1][2] = m12;
    d_p32[1][3] = m13;

    d_p32[2][0] = m20;
    d_p32[2][1] = m21;
    d_p32[2][2] = m22;
    d_p32[2][3] = m23;

    d_p32[3][0] = m30;
    d_p32[3][1] = m31;
    d_p32[3][2] = m32;
    d_p32[3][3] = m33;
}

_4matrix::_4matrix(void)
{
    d_p32[0][0] = 1;
    d_p32[0][1] = 0;
    d_p32[0][2] = 0;
    d_p32[0][3] = 0;

    d_p32[1][0] = 0;
    d_p32[1][1] = 1;
    d_p32[1][2] = 0;
    d_p32[1][3] = 0;

    d_p32[2][0] = 0;
    d_p32[2][1] = 0;
    d_p32[2][2] = 1;
    d_p32[2][3] = 0;

    d_p32[3][0] = 0;
    d_p32[3][1] = 0;
    d_p32[3][2] = 0;
    d_p32[3][3] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Нашёл ошибку. в `union
  {
   _4point d_4p32[4];
   _point d_p32[4][4];
   _32un d_u32[4][4];
  };` вот она `_4point d_4p32[4];`

Answer (score 1):

> dexmath.h(465): error C2280: '_4matrix::_4matrix(const _4matrix &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Это буквально переводится как:

> dexmath.h(465): ошибка C2280: '_4matrix::_4matrix(const _4matrix &)': попытка использовать (сослаться на) удаленную функцию.

Похоже, что вы там удалили функцию, а в коде все еще ее вызываете. Посмотрите, что на 465й строке вызывается в `dexmath.h`.

Очень надеюсь, что вы используете систему контроля версий и можете откатить историю и посмотреть, что же за функция там вызывалась.

Comment: на 465 строке`inline static _4matrix identity(void)
  {
   return _4matrix();
  }`